# Subfascia size rafter tail mismatch

Tags: framing, roof, construction

I'm in the process of redoing the fascia + soffits on my house. My roof framing consists of trusses with 2x4 top chords (so the tails are 3.5" tall). I'm planning on doing a 2x8 subfascia (7.25" tall), with aluminum fascia over the top.

My question is - are there any concerns with having a subfascia that is substantially larger than the rafter (truss) tails? (in this case they would be twice the height). The potential issue I'm thinking of would be around inadequate fastening, given only 50% of the subfascia board would be contacting the truss tails. This may increase the risk of sagging/warping/cupping of the subfascia over time?

I'm thinking I could attach some short 2x8 blocks to the tails to provide a larger fastening surface, but that isn't something I've seen done before. Every other instance of roof framing I've come across has subfascia matching the tails pretty closely (within an inch or two).

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Using two-by and not one-by? You're fine. But why taller though. That's just housing for wasps. Only concern is fascia has gutter above and drip edge below it.

Comment: @Mazura yeah using two-by mainly to give the gutters more meat to fasten into - I'm in snow country and the gutters here take a lot of weight. I want the fascia to be taller mainly for aesthetic reasons (not a fan of the look of a thin fascia line on a roof).

Comment: @Mazura can you explain what you mean by - "Only concern is fascia has gutter above and drip edge below it."? There is no drip edge below the fascia (drip edge is above the fascia, and above the gutter). Thanks.

Comment: They're all necessary parts of a roof system. *Shorter* would be no good (no drip edge). Taller is just for aesthetics (and **wasps** {my *one* and only concern here}). Trim coil, gutter, drip edge, on any size fascia you want that isn't smaller than the tails. - Fastening a 2x8 to 2x4s with two 3" deck screws every 16" be fine I think. Move up to construction lags if you're worried.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you were saying now. Thanks.